# Role of cache stride while flushing CPU cache

Tags: cpu-cache

I understand that the stride value of a CPU cache can be equal to or greater than the cache line size, but I don't understand why a stride value is required?

1. When will a CPU cache have a stride value which is larger than the cache line size?
2. When is stride value actually used? Is it while flushing?

I have searched around a lot for more on CPU cache stride, but couldn't find much information.

Answer (score 6):

A **stride** is a property of the memory access pattern, and has nothing to do with the cache hardware, as such.

For example, a memory access pattern `R(0), R(2), R(4),..` has stride `2`, where `R` denotes `read`, and number in bracket is the  address of a byte in memory. A pattern `R(0), R(15), R(30)` ... has stride 15.

The total memory capacity of a cache is divided into lines of equal size. A cache **line size** is the size (in bytes) of a single line in the cache. This *is* a parameter of the cache hardware.

Now, the length of a stride, relative to a cache line size, can affect the performance of a cache. If the stride is much smaller than a line size, many successive accesses will go to the same line in a cache. If the stride is larger than a cache line size, successive accesses will go to different cache lines. If the total number of accesses is fixed, the former case is typically much faster than the later. To understand why, try searching for how a cpu cache is organized.

Comment: neha, the CPUs spec itself defines both a cache line size as well as cache stride size. (For example the Intel Itanium series of processors). Different cache levels can have a stride value which is smaller than the cache line size.

Comment: Can you post a link where this is mentioned?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the word "stride" is used with the same meaning as my answer in most documentation related to caches. Eg, for stride value of 4 bytes the bandwidth of the cache port is some X GB/s. The stride is a property of the memory access pattern, not cache.

Comment: On Itanium series of CPUs, the CPU f/w implements PAL_CACHE_INFO to fetch the information of the cache. The spec is available on Itanium SDM Vol2 from Intel. http://www.intel.com/design/itanium/manuals/iiasdmanual.htm I agree that stride plays a role in memory access, which in turn decides how the data should be fetched into the cache line.